# How much does -Xmx affect JVM startup time?

Tags: java, jvm

How much does a large `-Xmx` setting affect JVM startup time?

Specifically, I am trying to evaluate whether for a server jvm it is better to set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value.

The only reference I can find is in [an old JRockit documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15060/tune_startup.htm#JRPTG211) which says that using an oversized heap can lead to longer than necessary JVM startup times.

Are there any statistics available how this affects modern JVMs?

Comment: Why not measure it on your particular workload? That'll give you far better information than someone without access to your environment could.

Comment: You question cannot have a generic answer, because it depends on the VM version, what you run in it and what environment the VM runs in. Generally, larger heaps tend to cause fewer, but longer garbage collections.

Comment: Thanks all. Unfortunately my workload is not any particular but trying to establish guidelines for a general purpose software. Though I am primarily interested in startup time, the commend about garbage collections is useful.